# params['_source'] in Elasticsearch is returning same source always

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

```
GET /locations/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "5000km",
          "geo_location": [
            -70,
            40
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "distance_in_m": {
      "script": "doc['geo_location'].arcDistance(40, -70)"
    },
    "data" : {
              "script" : "params['_source']"
          }
  }
}
```

The above queries is returning the same response in data and the distance is different.
It returns the last document's source
.

Comment: could you provide a response of this request with [profiing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are really interested in `_source` along with the scripted field, then do add `_source: true` in the query instead of adding as a scripted field.

```
GET /locations/_search
{
  "_source": true,                  <------------ Notice this
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "5000km",
          "geo_location": [
            -70,
            40
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "distance_in_m": {
      "script": "doc['geo_location'].arcDistance(40, -70)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did this yesterday but to my surprise, it was returning the same document record in source value for all the documents in response.

Comment: However, what helped the changing the geo_location values from array format to dictionary. I am answering below.

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /locations/_search
{
  "_source": true,  
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "5000km",
          "geo_location":{"lat": 40, "lon":-70}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "distance_in_m": {
      "script": "doc['geo_location'].arcDistance(40, -70)"
    }
  }
}
```

Changing "geo_location" values from array to dict format inside filters along with "_source" set to True helped.